# Will call API when load xib in iOS?

Tags: ios, storyboard, xib

When I open a xib file as source code, I find some code like :

```
<fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="16"/>
```

When this xib file loading, will it call the `UIFont` API?

Comment: Why ask this ? just curious.

Comment: I expect do some adaptation when xib file load. Like increase fontSize if display in 5.5 inch iPhone

Comment: why does it matter then if it calls the UIFont API, why not just increase your labels font size in `awakeFromNib` ? seems a strange way about increasing font sizes

Comment: You probably won't need to view XIB / Storyboard as source code. No point to do so.

Comment: If it calls UIFont API, I can change the method in runtime. And it will save a lot of code.

Comment: Not related. You have to understand how XIB works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it calls UIFont API. I tested this:

```
//
//  UIFont+Swizzled.m
//  Test
//
//  Created by Brandon T on 2016-02-29.
//  Copyright © 2016 Test. All rights reserved.
//

#import "UIFont+Swizzled.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIFont (Swizzled)

+ (void)load {
    //Quick and dirty swizzle. Should really only run once and check if method is added.. but w/e..

    Method original, swizzled;

    original = class_getClassMethod(self, @selector(fontWithName:size:));
    swizzled = class_getClassMethod(self, @selector(fontWithNameX:size:));
    method_exchangeImplementations(original, swizzled);

    original = class_getClassMethod(self, @selector(fontWithSize:));
    swizzled = class_getClassMethod(self, @selector(fontWithSizeX:));
    method_exchangeImplementations(original, swizzled);

    original = class_getClassMethod(self, @selector(systemFontOfSize:));
    swizzled = class_getClassMethod(self, @selector(systemFontOfSizeX:));
    method_exchangeImplementations(original, swizzled);

    original = class_getClassMethod(self, @selector(fontWithDescriptor:size:));
    swizzled = class_getClassMethod(self, @selector(fontWithDescriptorX:size:));
    method_exchangeImplementations(original, swizzled);
}

+ (nullable UIFont *)fontWithNameX:(NSString *)fontName size:(CGFloat)fontSize {
    return [self fontWithNameX:fontName size:fontSize];
}

- (UIFont *)fontWithSizeX:(CGFloat)fontSize {
    return [self fontWithSizeX:fontSize];
}

+ (UIFont *)systemFontOfSizeX:(CGFloat)fontSize {
    return [self systemFontOfSizeX:fontSize];
}

+ (UIFont *)fontWithDescriptorX:(UIFontDescriptor *)descriptor size:(CGFloat)pointSize {
    return [self fontWithDescriptorX:descriptor size:pointSize];
}
@end
```

Then I created a blank storyboard with a single controller, added a label to it, and changed the font to Helvetica Neue of size 17.

Next, I included the above category file into my controller associated with the story board.

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  Test
//
//  Created by Brandon T on 2016-02-27.
//  Copyright © 2016 Test. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "UIFont+Swizzled.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

The results:

```
2016-02-29 22:12:19.585 Test[94691:4139779] systemFontOfSize -- Size:17.000000

2016-02-29 22:12:19.586 Test[94691:4139779] fontWithDescriptor  -- Descriptor: UICTFontDescriptor <0x7fe60340e770> = {
    NSFontNameAttribute = HelveticaNeue;
    NSFontSizeAttribute = 17;
}, Size:17.000000
```

So it calls TWO things. `SystemFontOfSize` first.. then it calls `FontWithDescriptor`.

Comment: @OP; I must say though.. it's a weird question.. I don't know why you need to know this..

Comment: I expect do some adaptation when xib file load. Like increase fontSize if display in 5.5 inch iPhone. Your answer really helpful for my issue !